Induced action on fundamental group
I encountered this problem on a practice exam (without sample solution): Identify $S^2$ with $\mathbb{C} \cup \infty$. Let $X_n = S^2\backslash\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ denote $S^2$ minus the N-th roots of unity. Take $n = 3$ for convenience. Now, observe that $\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$ acts on $X_3$ by multiplication. What is the induced action on $\pi_1(X_3, 0)$ using generators and relations?
My attempt: First, $X_n$ is just $S^2$ minus n points, so it deformation retracts to two poles of the 2 sphere with n arcs going from one pole to another, which deformation retracts to a wedge of n-1 circles. Now, the action would be rotating the arcs in the second step (i.e. sending arc 1 to arc 2, arc 2 to arc 3, arc 3 to arc 1), and if we label them as a, b, and c, the action sends $a \mapsto b$, $b \mapsto c$, and $c \mapsto a$. The loops would be $ba^{-1}$ and $bc^{-1}$ so all we need to do is to plug it in.
I'm not so sure about my operation in bold text. Is this correct (and why is this correct)?

The bold text is correct. Is there a specific part of it you're confused about?

@Frank Is there a way to do the same thing on the wedge of 2 circles? I couldn’t figure out how the action would work on the loops that way.

What do you mean by "do the same thing"? A wedge of $2$ circles would correspond to $S^2$ minus three points, and you can use the action as you described it above.
